# How do I pass a variable argument to instanceof?

Tags: java, oop, instanceof

I am looking for a way to pass the argument c to instanceof, because i need to loop through an array like shown in the code, but the compiler returns the error "unknown class c" How do I fix this?

```
Class0 a = new Class0();
boolean bool;
Class[] array = new Class[]{Class0.class, Class1.class};
for(Class c : array){
   if(a instanceof c)
       bool = true;
   else
      bool = false;
}
```

I know I could use a.getClass().getSimpleName() and check if it's equal to an element in an array of Strings, but I'd like to understand better how to use the keyword instanceof and how it works.

Comment: c.getClass() would be the solution

Comment: I worry that this might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) type question. Rather than focus on your attempted solution, consider telling us the details of the underlying problem that you're trying to use this solution to solve.

Comment: Class has `isAssignableFrom` or `isInstance` methods. Check them.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels well spotted mate,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't - the `instanceof` *operator* always takes the name of a type as its second operand. However, you can use the [`Class.isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) *method* instead:

```
bool = c.isInstance(a);
```

Note the lack of an if/else - any time you have `if (condition) return true; else return false;` or the like, you can collapse it. However, in your current code, the value of `bool` after the loop will only depend on the *last* element of the array, as you're reassigning it on every iteration.

You may *actually* want:

```
boolean bool = false;
for (Class c : array){
   if (c.isInstance(a))
       bool = true;
   }
}
```

(With Java 8 you could do that using streams and `anyMatch`, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Right thinking, but the method name is actually isInstance().

Comment: Shouldn't the "may actually want" body use `isInstance` instead of `instanceof` as well?